# Seeing a refraction effect not only for scene BG but also for 3D models

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to apply a refraction material to sphere object. I need to see through this sphere not only a scene background but also other 3D geometry located in the scene. I can setup `envMap` parameter using `Scene.background`.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

scene.background = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().setPath( '/path/to/my/assets/' )
                                                 .load( [ 'pX.png', 'nX.png', 
                                                          'pY.png', 'nY.png', 
                                                          'pZ.png', 'nZ.png' ] );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 50, 25, 15 );

var refractedMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xfffffc, 
                                                      envMap: scene.background, 
                                             refractionRatio: 1.00 } );

var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, refractedMaterial );

// And here are some 3D text for example...
// I can see this 3D text in my scene 
// but I can't see it thru refractive sphere
var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeometry, textMaterial );

scene.add( sphereMesh );
scene.add( textMesh );
```

QUESTION:

**What parameter of `MeshBasicMaterial( parameters : Object )` is responsible for visibility of scene geometry, not only a scene background**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of refraction technique does not do what you are looking for. It just works with the given environment map/background but not with other objects in the scene.

You might want to use `THREE.Refractor` which makes it possible to honor other objects in your scene. Check out the official demo to see its usage in action:

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_refraction

However, `THREE.Refractor` only works with flat surfaces so you can't apply it to a sphere geometry.